# Detect when a function is called in another component.

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components in my Angular 2 app - `folder-selector.component.ts` and `home.component.ts`. These components work together to display a file system tree view - basically, a file browser. When I click a folder in the tree view, a function called `nodeSelect(event)` is called.

How do I go about notifying `home.component.ts` that `nodeSelect(event)` inside `folder-selector.component.ts` was called? `nodeSelect(event)` performs some logic to set a string variable which I need inside `home.component.ts` - I know how to get it but I do not know how to get it immediately (whenever `nodeSelect(event)` is called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EventEmitter for this. Something like this:

```
class FolderSelectorComponent {
   @Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   nodeSelect() {
        this.myEvent.emit('someStringValue');
    }
}
```

//Sample of your parent component Home

```
  @Component({
        selector : 'home',
        template : `
            <folder-selector (myEvent)="doSomething($event)"></folder-selector>`,
        directives : [FolderSelector]
    })
    class Home {
        doSomething(evt) {    } //Where evt is 'someStringValue'
    }
```